# Choice of UI library to create amazing Windows Desktop App

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, user-experience

I want to develop a desktop app for Windows, and have recently contacted a designer to make the wireframes I've made really awesome. After the design is finished, I want it to be ported 100% to the app.

As in web development, this is the normal process. You create the design, and then from the PSD files you create the website using HTML and CSS, which is normally not a bit problem for someone who knows what he's doing.

Doing this for the windows app, I'm not so sure. What I'm looking at is a design that is totally not standard, all the elements and the design is totally different from a normal look and standard elements like buttons, forms etc. will look totally different.

The question now is: **What's the best option to accomplish this?**

I've read alot lately about the GUI implementation possibilities, and what I've come across is that WPF is the way to go, that it's really flexible, and the fact that it uses a similar approach like HTML for building the UI gives me hope that it's possible.

So, a question to all the UI experts out here: What technology / UI library would be best to use? Is .NET with WPF powerful enough to create a 100% nonstandard design? I'm looking at custom graphs and charts as well.

Looking forward to your input!

Comment: [Here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) is an example of what you can do with WPF

Comment: Are we talking about a Windows store app or a proper Windows Desktop application?

Comment: It's about a Desktop Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume we're talking about a desktop software and not a Windows Store app. If I got you wrong here, the answer remains more or less the same. Building a store app reduces complexity a bit, the basic principles and processes are the same, nonetheless.

WPF is definitely the way to go. You really can do almost anything you can imagine, from 3D over complex storyboard animations, etc., etc.. WPF allows you to organize a complex styling task in a way that it remains manageable and scalable. Apart from that WPF is a great framework, I don't even know any alternative which doesn't mean there aren't any. Windows Forms is no option for you.

With WPF you develop your app in a framework that will be there for quite a while in the future, has a huge community and large number of third party distributors of control- and extension-frameworks.

From the development side, you have a number of powerful IDEs to develop your app, Visual Studio first of all. In theory, there is a workflow from Photoshop via Blend (designer tool) to Visual Studio (developer tool). While Visual Studio (VS) is (more or less undoubtedly) the best IDE available, I've never got used to Blend.

So, first part of the answer is: WPF is the framework for your requirements and I cannot even suggest any inferior alternatives.

**BUT**:

Don't underestimate what it means to build an app as you're planning in WPF. Just learning WPF and MVVM (the design pattern that goes hand in hand with WPF) properly - I mean really properly - which you must to build a completely individual app, will keep you busy for months! Don't be scared, it is possible and it is worth it, but plan realistically...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was a nice clarification, and it pushed me into the right direction.

Comment: @ChrisPreston: Great to hear that, good luck with your project!!